# Seeking municipal-level administrative boundary data for Poland?

Tags: data, poland

I am looking for municipal-level administrative boundary data (NUTS 5) for Poland. Since it is public information, I thought the data would be readily available, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. I have checked the usual sources. [GADM](http://www.gadm.org) has data down to the county (powiat) level, and [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com) seems to only have data down to the provincial level. I have looked at many of the Polish government's sites, but while I can find plenty of GIS data viewers, I can't find a way to download the administrative boundary data I am interested in. To make matters more complicated, I would really like historic data, but I would settle for current NUTS 5 level data.

Comment: any update on this? I am looking for the same data?

Comment: @Justin Not much of an update. I looked all over and ended up having to buy the data.

Comment: @PolyGeo As far as I can tell, none of those datasets in the link above provides NUTS-5 level data for Poland. This is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Then you need to [edit] your question to make clear that you have reviewed the suggested duplicate, and highlight what is different about what you are asking. However, if there's any chance that this is open data then the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange may be a more suitable site for researching/asking this.

Comment: As the question is already closed, I put it here: I used these data that include also municipal level (LAU) in Poland: https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try contacting [Francis Harvey](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~fharvey/UMN-FH-Site/Welcome.html), one of the Co-Directors of the MGIS program at the University of Minnesota. He does a lot of GIS research in Poland, and is probably very well aware of what is and is not publicly available.

Comment: According to Prof. Harvey, the data is very tough to get without paying for it. If I understand him correctly, he doesn't have it either.

Answer (score 3):

NUTS 5 ([***gmina***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmina)) is the most detailed level of administrative structure in Poland.

It's been a while since I left my homeland, but ***as far as I am aware*** it will not be possible to obtain such dataset for free.

For a quick overview have a look at [geoportal.gov.pl](http://maps.geoportal.gov.pl/webclient/) - web map service of national mapping agency.

You might also post a question on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/group/pl.comp.gis/topics) to get more up to date info or some pointers to where you could purchase this kind of data.

Comment: @radek just want to mention (as it is your homeland :)) that there is data available via the `global administrative boundaries` link that I posted.

Comment: @celenius: GADM [docs](http://www.gadm.org/Poland) specify that there are levels 0, 1 and 2 available. Which gets you down to county (powiat) level (one above gmina) - as Jason posted in the question. Additionally, comment from 2009 (same docs) also indicate that there might be some errors there. Perhaps I'm missing something? If yes - please provide a link - I know that would make a lot of Polish GIS users extremely happy ;]

Comment: @radek Apologies, I mixed up my sources - it's not available via GADM at that level of resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you have to purchase good quality data, i.e. here:

http://www.codgik.gov.pl/pastwowy-rejestr-granic-i-powierzchni-jednostek-podziaow-terytorialnych-kraju.html
or
http://mapycyfrowe.pl/

I have seen a post in polish at http://forum.cad.pl/mapa-powiatow-t72142.html. Where is suggested that you can get your data at specified link to sdi.geoportal.gov.pl. Data are in GML but you can convert it with Ogr2Ogr to anything you need. I do not know about licencing for that. Have a look.

You may also try to look around at http://www.openstreetmap.org/ as you can download .shp data from there (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles#Download_shapefiles_of_OSM_data). But even if the data are available, the quality is doubtful.

Sadly, availability of GIS data in Poland is quite limited, not to mention free GIS data.

Comment: Thank you. About a year ago I managed to extract gmina-level data from sdi.geoportal.gov.pl; however, I had trouble in the conversion to other formats (projection issues, etc), and when I did get the data converted, the IDs for each region were incorrect. I am not a geographer by training and I decided it would probably be a good idea to get the data through more legitimate channels.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether this question is still open, but you might want to check out the Eurostat website, which hosts some valuable information on the NUTS system including maps, metadata and shapefiles for download:

http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/nuts_nomenclature/introduction

They also seem to have an archive section with older NUTS versions, but I haven't checked this out in detail yet.

Comment: Thank you, @bero80. I am aware of the Eurostat site. As it turns out, purchased the data 2011 data from [GfK Geomarketing](http://www.gfk-geomarketing.com) with some grant money I had available. It wasn't cheap, and they only had the 2011 data available, but they did offer me an educational discount that made it worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

Please check below link, it provides municipal (Gminy) level data for Poland

http://www.codgik.gov.pl/index.php/darmowe-dane/prg.html

Comment: Wow, thank you. I will start downloading this right away. Is this a new service?

Comment: Welcome, Dont know if its a new service but I had the same requirement and after digging through several sites came across this link.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I played with NUTS level data there was hardly anything publicly available below NUTS-2 or 3. Unless there has been a major break through in openness by European NMA in the last five years I'd guess you are out of luck. A quick [google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=european%20nuts%205%20boundary) seems to confirm this (though as I don't speak Polish there may be sites out there I'm missing but I can't find equivalent for the UK)

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you may be correct. I may just have to try to find someone to pay for the data for me.