# Poland ZIP code shapefile?

Tags: data, point, csv, zip-codes, poland

I'm looking for Poland zip-code data (polygons). I have found data in csv on the http://www.geonames.org/ but there are only point data.

Do you know any free source containing this data?

Comment: www.gadm.org should have it covered

Comment: Unfortunately this data doesn’t contain zip-code areas.

Comment: German postcode boundaries are at https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/pcboundaries/ , maybe if you ask him he'll run his toolchain for poland (if the data is in OSM, which I don't know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to find free layer polygon for Polish postal codes will be very difficult. You can find several companies offering this kind of GIS data, for example.

[Imagis](http://imagis.pl/pl/content/mapa-kod%C3%B3w-pocztowych)

Comment: Janek, if you are still looking for zip-codes shapefiles look here, maybe it help you: [link](http://www.codgik.gov.pl/index.php/darmowe-dane/prg.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any free source of ZIP code shapefile, doesn't mean it is not out there. Like @til_b suggested you can ask for a custom process to try to capture the data you like. I've seen examples in web maps [here](http://mapa-kodow-pocztowych.pl/) so it is available but for a fee in most if not all cases. There was a previous GIS SE [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/16500/35779) that might provide another outlet to reach your dataset.